# Perform query with meta_value date

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query, meta-query

I am trying to perform a query on a custom-type post using the value of a custom field. 
This field contains a string date: dd.mm.yyyy.
The post type name is 'event'
The custom field name is 'date_event'

I would like to show all the EVENT that have the month of DATE_EVENT matching with the current month.

Any suggestion pls?

Comment: show what you have tried. the first step is to reverse the order of the dates you're storing to be in [MySQL date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) format - yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: you mean that the value must not be a string but a MySql date?

Comment: a string, but the units should be in descending order from large to small- year, month, day. if you think of the dates as just one big number, and then adding, subtracting, comparing them, it makes sense why it should be in that order.

Comment: ok, done. but now how can i use this value to perform my query?

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: I have thought to another solution because i need to perform pagination too...and i think that this could complicate the things...I have created a new post type(page) with a group of field where i will insert the ids of the posts related to a specific month. So i will formulate the query using the array of ids for each page(month). This way will be easier to create a pagination sistem of those page too!

Answer (score 4):

I did something similar, the technique you need to use is called a meta query.

Here is the query I wrote to get posts based on a date value stored as a custom field meta value.

```
query_posts(
array(
'post_type'=>'post',
'order'=>'ASC',
'orderby'=>'meta_value_num',
'meta_key'=>'date_event',
'posts_per_page'=> -1,
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
           'key' => 'date_event',
           'value' => $startDate, // Lowest date value
           'compare' => '>='
       ),
       array(
           'key' => 'date_event',
           'value' => $endDate, // Highest date value
           'compare' => '<='
       )
   )
));
```

`'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` will sort the results by the meta value

`'meta_key' => 'date_event'` tells what the custom field is called

`meta_query` is an array which specifies that the results must match both conditions, then we specify a minimum date and a maximum date.

The date values must be stored either as `YYYY-MM-DD` or as a "Seconds since the Unix Epoch" value.